# Making custom checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make some basic custom checkboxes using css and jquery. I have this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>

    <style>

        input[type="checkbox"]{
        /*display:none;*/
        }
        .label .checkbox{
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1000;
        padding:2px 3px 0 0;
        }
        .label .checkbox .circle{
        display:none;
        background-color:#af213c;
        line-height:25px;
        text-align:center;
        z-index:0;
        border-radius:600px;
        -moz-border-radius:600px;
        -webkit-border-radius:600px;
        height:23px;
        width:23px;
        }
        .label{
        padding-right:34px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-family: "b yekan";
        }
        .label:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
        }
        .labelcheck{
        color:#af213c;
        }
        .labelcheck .checkbox .circle{
        display:block;
        }
        .labelcheck .checkbox{
        z-index:0;
        }


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
                <label id="new" for="remember">remember me:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="data[remember]" id="remember"     value="1">           

                <script>
                $('input[type="checkbox"][id="remember"]').prev('label').append("<div class='checkbox'><div class='circle'></div></div>");
                $('input[type="checkbox"][id="remember"]').prev('label').addClass('label');
                var $chbx = $('input[type="checkbox"][id="remember"]')
                $chbx.onchange=function() {
                var label = $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]');
                     if(this.checked=true) {
                        label.addClass('labelcheck');
                     }
                     else if (this.checked=false){
                        label.addClass('label');
                     }
                 };


           </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Copy it and see. I wanted to change the label's class so that I could style each states of the checkbox. So I used onchange to relate labels class to checkbox state. Class of the label is not changing. But it may have other problems, but I can't realize that.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: `if(this.checked=true) {` should be `if(this.checked===true) {` and then change the `else if(this.checked=false) {` to `else {`.

Comment: ...and use a tool like http://jshint.com to find simple, common mistakes. This is part of basic debugging that should take place before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things wrong in the jQuery:

1. Missing closing semicolon line 3
2. Use `$(this)` for jQuery obj, not `this`
3. Equality testing incorrect (== not just =)
4. `if(this.checked=true)` should be `if ($(this).prop('checked')==true)`

All mistakes that I've made myself in the recent past.

See [working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/F6v3J/)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="remember"]').prev('label').append("<div class='checkbox'><div class='circle'></div></div>");
$('input[type="checkbox"][id="remember"]').prev('label').addClass('label');
var $chbx = $('input[type="checkbox"][id="remember"]'); //missing closing semicolon
//alert($chbx.attr('id'));

$chbx.change(function() { //fixed formatting/syntax
    var label = $('label[for="' +$(this).attr('id')+ '"]');
    alert('CB property: ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true) {
        label.addClass('labelcheck').removeClass('label');
        alert('Label class changed to: [' + label.attr('class') + ']');
    } else if ($(this).prop('checked')==false){
        label.removeClass('labelcheck').addClass('label');
        alert('Label class changed to: [' + label.attr('class') + ']');
}
});
```

Comment: You're welcome; I hope it does what you need. Please remember to choose a correct answer when satisfied, in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make checkbox function like this,

```
             $chbx.click(function() {
              var label = $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]');
                 if(this.checked) {

                    label.removeClass('label');
                    label.addClass('labelcheck');
                 }
                 else{
                    label.removeClass('labelcheck');
                    label.addClass('label');
                 }
             });
```